# How do you stop a running geth node?

Tags: go-ethereum, clients

I can not figure out how to stop a running geth node without killing the process. I tried to lookup `geth help` but there is no mention of stopping, halting or any shutdown command.

How to shutdown geth cleanly?

#### Edit:

I'm running it as a **daemon**, CTRL+C is no option.

Comment: And how do I stop it if the Wallet crashed and Geth is still running as task in Windows? I use the task manager and stop the task but I fear it could harm something (even so it looks like it did not when I had to use it several times before).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because you ran geth as a daemon you can either:

```
killall -HUP geth
```

in one line, or get the pid with:

```
ps ax | grep geth
```

and kill it with kill

```
kill -HUP <pid>
```

`-HUP` is the sighup signal, is optional but is more gentle than the normal `TERM` signal.

Comment: Instead of running `ps` and piping it to `grep`, you can use `pgrep geth`. One-liner: `kill -HUP $(pgrep geth)`.

Comment: Or even `pkill -HUP geth`

Comment: It continuously resurrect after kill

Comment: If you check the [code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/cef3e2dc5a563fccb4c54b7bea2fddc071bf9541/console/console.go#L359) of Geth only SIGINT and SIGTERM are supported for graceful shutdown. SIGHUP should not be used and ongoing with Geth 1.10.0 you'll get a warning at the next start that Geth did not shutdown propperly if you do so. There was also a discussion about this in the GitHub issues and ultimately it was decided to only support those two signals.

Answer (score 13):

use `Ctrl c` or

```
kill -INT <pid>
```

if you started `geth` with `console`, you exit with `Ctrl D` or

```
> exit
```

Comment: Is there really no command to stop a node?

Comment: @5chdn if your already in console, its fast to do `Ctrl+c` than opening up a new terminal tab to kill this.

Comment: @5chdn I hear you bro. Something like bitcoin-cli stop, right? One would think that Ctrl+C or pkill don't let the program close well, but maybe they do?

Answer (score 12):

## When running in console

Geth can be stopped by sending it a keyboard interrupt with `Ctrl + c`.  You should see output similar to the following.

```
I0127 09:46:49.971487   62813 blockchain.go:1230] imported 1 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 0 txs in 2.836192ms. #913170 [2eb50f50 / 2eb50f50]
^C
I0127 09:46:54.258683   62813 cmd.go:123] Got interrupt, shutting down...
I0127 09:46:54.259731   62813 blockchain.go:677] Chain manager stopped
I0127 09:46:54.259774   62813 handler.go:191] Stopping ethereum protocol handler...
I0127 09:46:54.259797   62813 handler.go:201] Ethereum protocol handler stopped
I0127 09:46:54.259813   62813 transaction_pool.go:150] Transaction pool stopped
I0127 09:46:54.259831   62813 backend.go:630] Automatic pregeneration of ethash DAG OFF (ethash dir: /home/user/.ethash)
I0127 09:46:54.260551   62813 database.go:158] closed db: /home/user/.ethereum/chaindata
I0127 09:46:54.260716   62813 database.go:158] closed db: /home/user/.ethereum/dapp
```

In the event that go-ethereum receives multiple interrupts before shutting down cleanly, you should see something like this.

```
I0127 09:50:47.173412   63063 cmd.go:129] Already shutting down, please be patient.
I0127 09:50:47.173433   63063 cmd.go:130] Interrupt 9 more times to induce panic.
```

In this case if you continue to hit `Ctrl + c` to force the process to quit you may corrupt the underlying databases that go-ethereum maintains.

## Killing a Daemon Process

If the process is running as a daemon, then you can kill it with `kill -INT <pid>` where `<pid` is the process id for the running `geth` process.

One way to find the process id is with `ps aux | grep geth`.

```
$ ps aux | grep geth
user           63353  91.2  0.2 573457444  29844 s019  R+   10:15AM   0:01.97 geth --rpc
user           63355   0.0  0.0  2434836    780 s021  S+   10:15AM   0:00.00 grep geth
```

Here the `pid` that should be killed is `63353`.

Comment: CTRL+C is no option, geth runs as daemon.

Comment: Updated with info on killing a daemon process.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use

```
pkill -INT geth
```

which will reuslt in the same as pressing CTRL-C in geth console:

```
...
INFO [01-13|12:17:53] Imported new chain segment...
INFO [01-13|12:17:57] Got interrupt, shutting down... 
INFO [01-13|12:17:57] HTTP endpoint closed: http://...:8545 
INFO [01-13|12:17:57] IPC endpoint closed: /.../.ethereum/geth.ipc 
INFO [01-13|12:17:57] Blockchain manager stopped 
INFO [01-13|12:17:57] Stopping Ethereum protocol
```

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl D and then exit worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running ps and piping it to grep, you can use pgrep geth.
One-liner: `kill -HUP $(pgrep geth)`.
– Diti Aug 13 '17 at 12:36

I did not see the above as an answer, but as a response to one of the answers. I used `kill -HUP $(pgrep geth)` and it worked perfectly, so thank you Diti

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command:

`sudo systemctl stop geth`