# Is it safe to kill geth with SIGTERM?

Tags: go-ethereum

Unlike SIGINT it gives no output to console except "terminated". I tried it with testnet and it seemed ok. But is it safe to do so?

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/709/how-do-you-stop-a-running-geth-node/715#715

Comment: Thank you @BadrBellaj. -HUP signal works fine, but it outputs "Hangup" instead of "Got interrupt, shutting down..., sync stopped..., db is closed.., etc." Does it mean it exits gracefully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I was wondering about this today... )

From the code, the safest and cleanest way to shut Geth down is using a `SIGINT`, either in the form of a CTRL+C, or by sending the signal directly to the process using `kill -INT <pid>`. Geth doesn't handle `SIGTERM`s in the same, clean way.

`SIGTERM`s and `SIGHUP`s do **not** lead to graceful shut down.

At various places in the code, Geth registers for notification of interrupt signals (i.e. `SIGINT`s):

```
    sigc := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigc, os.Interrupt)
```

Depending on what Geth is doing, it can then handle `SIGINT`s gracefully, for example:

- It can [gracefully abort the import of chaindata](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/ac93a6ff6cd1200ab0fb67a5bd0c02cb70646632/cmd/utils/cmd.go#L108), by calling `checkInterrupt()` before each block of data is imported.
- If the interrupt happens [early enough](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/ac93a6ff6cd1200ab0fb67a5bd0c02cb70646632/cmd/utils/cmd.go#L73), the node can be shut down before anything meaty has happened at all.

---

Outside of Geth, there are examples where `SIGTERM`s *are* handled gracefully:

In the [Swarm code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/9b161187ec130841bf4d04945cdcf45c221739fc/cmd/swarm/main.go#L278), and, more importantly perhaps, in the [C++ implementation](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/blob/e66eef91f7620adf3e09e26462198a22ae2c1dc8/eth/main.cpp#L1300), which registers the same exit handler for both `SIGTERM`s and `SIGINT`s in its `main()` function:

```
signal(SIGABRT, &ExitHandler::exitHandler);
signal(SIGTERM, &ExitHandler::exitHandler);
signal(SIGINT, &ExitHandler::exitHandler);
```

Comment: I tried to kill geth with SIGTERM and it seems it worked ok. The chain data remained valid and the node started again with no problems. I guess I was just lucky) AFAIU there is no handler for SIGTERM inside geth?

Comment: I think you were just lucky :) If your node had been part-way through writing a database record, or something similar, you would have likely ended up with corrupt chaindata. _Inside_ Geth there don't appear to be any SIGTERM handlers, no. The underlying OS will be handling the signal and killing the process.