# Fatal: Error starting protocol stack

Tags: installation

I'm having a problem on a new ethereum install on a Mac:

`Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: listen udp :30303: bind: address already in use`

Any suggestions to fix would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You might have already installed and launched an geth instance before. It might as well be other services listen on the same port, though very unlikely.

You can use the following command to kill the existing process:

```
$ # Get <PID> of the process occupying the port
$ lsof -i tcp:30303
$ kill -QUIT <PID>
```

Then reload the wallet.

Comment: It would be better to try `kill -INT <pid>` first as Geth has an explicit handler for  `SIGINT`s but not for `SIGQUIT`s. That way if there _is_ an instance already running, it's more likely to exit gracefully. (Also, a `QUIT` signal leads to an explicit core dump.) http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10566/is-it-safe-to-kill-geth-with-sigterm/12196#12196

Comment: Tried kill -INT <pid> first, still had issue, then used kill -QUIT <PID>, issue solved!

Comment: Glad to know it's resolved!