# Data integrity after Go Ethereum crashes

Tags: go-ethereum

If my Geth node crashes during normal sync or `--fast` sync, can the integrity of the node's blockchain database be guaranteed or is there a risk that some transactions or even blocks (in the case of a `--fast` sync) didn't get written to the node's filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only real way to guarantee integrity of the data is if a `SIGINT` was issued and subsequently gracefully handled.

This [previous answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/12196/52) details Geth's signal handling during the importing of the chaindata.

A "crash" wouldn't normally accompany a `SIGINT` (nor vice versa).