# How do I keep geth running? --daemon doesn't work

Tags: go-ethereum, daemon

So I run

```
geth --testnet --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,web3" console
```

But when I exit out of putty geth stops.

I tried to add:

```
--daemon
```

But it didn't work.

How do I keep geth running?

Comment: Hi there. This is a general Linux question, as opposed to anything specific to Ethereum, so I'm going to suggest it be closed as off-topic. The answer is to use `screen`, or a similar utility.

Comment: For example: https://superuser.com/questions/96660/how-can-i-keep-a-process-alive-after-closing-the-putty-session

Comment: IMHO this question can be useful to have, along with an answer like @RichardHorrocks comment. If it gets closed, it might not be as searchable. But it's up to the community if it wants to close this.

Comment: Happy to leave this open if people think it'll be useful.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you close your Putty session it delivers a hang-up signal (`SIGHUP`) to the Geth daemon, which causes it to close. The Putty session is Geth's parent process, regardless of using the `--daemon` option, so its children will die with it.

Note that I think some care has to be taken when Geth closes in this way. I don't *think* Geth has proper signal handlers for `SIGHUP` which *could* mean that things aren't left in a clean state. (e.g. If you're syncing block data, then corruption of the data is a possible outcome.)

See the accepted answer to this thread: [Is it safe to kill geth with SIGTERM?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10566/is-it-safe-to-kill-geth-with-sigterm)

To prevent the daemon being killed in this way, you have a few options. The two that I've used in the past (for things unrelated to Ethereum) are either to redirect the `SIGHUP` so it isn't delivered to the process, or use a utility like `screen` (which I think is easier).

These threads ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309056/linux-minecraft-server-closes-when-i-exit-putty), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/96660/how-can-i-keep-a-process-alive-after-closing-the-putty-session)) from other Stack Exchange boards have more details.

Comment: congrats on 10k :)