# Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: datadir already used by another process on AWS EC2

Tags: go-ethereum, aws

I was running geth on my AWS instance. Due to timeout my connection to AWS was closed but geth was still running. When I logged back in to run the command again, it raised the following error:

`Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: datadir already used by another process`

How can log in into my geth console again?

Comment: Kill the geth process and start it again. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/709/how-do-you-stop-a-running-geth-node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can kill the previous process and restart it